# flink with python, execution of job failed

Tags: python, apache-flink, pyflink

For a first try I want to read JSON data from a file and pass it on to Flink. I defined a source (which reads JSON strings line by line) and a placeholder filter. See Code:

```
from org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source import SourceFunction
from org.apache.flink.api.common.functions import FilterFunction
import json
import sys

class Json_reader(SourceFunction):
    def readjason(self, ctx):
        sys.stdin = open('capture.json', 'r')
        for line in sys.stdin:
            ctx.collect(json.loads(line))


class Dummy_Filter(FilterFunction):
    def filter(self, value):
        return True

#
# The pipeline definition.
#
def main(factory):
    env = factory.get_execution_environment()
    env.create_python_source(Json_reader()) \
        .filter(Dummy_Filter()) \
        .output()
    env.execute()
```

When I build the job and move it to my started Flink-cluster, I get the following error message:

> VirtualBox:/media/sf_Python$ ./flink-1.7.2/bin/pyflink-stream.sh
>   ./json_parser_flink.py  Starting execution of program Failed to run
>   plan: null Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line
>   1, in    File
>   "/tmp/flink_streaming_plan_fbe13c4c-6918-46d4-a4bc-36908a2bea24/json_parser_flink.py",
>   line 25, in main  at
>   org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:268)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:487)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1510)
>     at
>   org.apache.flink.streaming.python.api.environment.PythonStreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(PythonStreamExecutionEnvironment.java:245)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException:
>   org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job
>   failed. (JobID: 31615948194c951be03d46576929aa23)
>
> The program didn't contain a Flink job. Perhaps you forgot to call
>   execute() on the execution environment.

I haven't forgotten to call execute().

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. Fast expects a run() function in the SourceFunction.